# Magento 2 : Product details page loading slowly?

Tags: product, magento2.2

In the site category page loading properly but when click on product detail page it's loading too slow. I have been checking exception log and it throws following error.

```
main.CRITICAL: The element 'product.info.options' already has a child with alias 'text' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element 'product.info.options' already has a child with alias 'text' at /home/shavershop/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611)"} []
```

can you help on this issue? It will be great.

Comment: The error you are seeing is not related to slow loading of page. You need to check through magento profiler, it will help you understand which part is taking time to load